# Owners list issues

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I'm trying to use the sdk and am unclear from the docs https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk.

Do I need to include owner1 in the owners array so that he can sign transactions after that? In your code its not clear what are the owners but after creating the safe, even though owner1 creates the safe, he can't sign transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referencing [deploying a new Safe](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk#2.-deploy-a-new-safe).

In this case it is indeed necessary to include all owners that should be able to confirm transactions (e.g. also the one deploying the Safe, in your case owner 1) into the list of initial owners.

The deployment of the Safe does not rely on the `msg.sender` this makes it easier to use relayers or even recreate the Safe on different networks easily.